# Saving PointCloud from Rosbag

Tags: python, ros, rosbag

I have to extract images and PCDs from a rosbag file.
I'm using Python 2 and `rosbag` library to iterate through messages:

```
import rosbag
from cv_bridge import CvBridge

bag = rosbag.Bag('test.bag')
bridge = CvBridge()
for topic, msg, t in self.bag.read_messages():
    # if image, use bridge
    # but what what to do to save a PointCloud into a PCD?
```

Is there some library (like `cv_bridge`) that can help me with extracting PCD from a rosbag?
I found [pypcd](https://github.com/dimatura/pypcd), but I don't know if it does what I hope it does, as it doesn't work in Python 2, and I can't make `rosbag` library work in Python 3...

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

[pcl_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros) has a tool to convert pointclouds from a bag file to PCD's.

```sh
rosrun pcl_ros bag_to_pcd <input_file.bag> <topic> <output_directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Conversion from message to PointCloud can be done like:

```
pc = PointCloud.from_msg(msg)
```

Conversion from PointCloud to message can be done like:

```
msg = pc.to_msg()
```

Comment: Do you do that in Python 2 or 3?
The questions was basically how to make pypcd work in Python 2, as installing it through pip requires Python 3.

Comment: In the end, I made it work by manually downloading pypcd code.

Comment: What is "PointCloud" in the first code snippet?

Comment: Imported via ```import pypcd```. See https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pypcd/latest/pypcd.pdf